Cant get File Audit Settings to generate events for folder creation
I am trying to monitor folder creation, moves and renames for a certain directory.
I have enabled "Audit File System" in group policy.
And have configured the folder audit settings per below.

When looking at the event log in regards to folders I have observed the following.

Creating Folders - No Event
Deleting Folders - 4663 Event with Delete Details
Folder Move - 4663 Event with Delete details for the folder being moved, 4663 Event with AddSubdirectory details for the parent of the folder getting the file added.

I would have expected some kind of event for just creating a folder, I would have also expected the move to also show this same event or have the name of the sub-directory being added in the add sub-directory event.
Is this standard and the information just isn't there, or have I misconfiugred something?

Defect. Report it to Microsoft. If you use their Bug Bounty program, they may give you some free cash. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/msrc/bounty

Just out of curiosity, what happens if you create a sub folder (parent folder first, then a sub folder), does that not get logged either? Which version of Windows 10 are you on?

Yea subfolders dont seem to register anything either, doing a rename does similar the same as a move as well. I have been doing this testing on on of my windows 10 VMs which doesnt get network connected so it is a little older version (10.0.19041). I will setup a new VM with a newer version to test.

@LuckyLuke I can confirm similar results on a fully updated windows server 2025 install
